# Storing object information in java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am making a small game in Java which involves guessing what the specified attribute belongs to (For example, what country does the city of Bogota belong to?).

My initial idea was to create a custom object which had the name as the first attribute and then the other attributes of the object (like shape, size, color) as the rest of the attributes. Then you would have a parent array containing these objects and to find the specific attribute of the object you would be guessing, it would pick a random number and select that number object from the array.

I am at the point where I am lost in how I should make this array. If I have 100 objects, it doesn't seem efficient to me to say, create an ArrayList of custom objects, then define each object individually with their attributes, then do list.add(object) 100 times.

Surely it does not make sense to create and store every object each time my main loop is run? Would there be a more effective way of putting each object into an array? Would there be a way to store each object into a file and my program retrieves the object and its information from a different file when I need to call it? I'm pretty new to this so maybe it doesn't make much sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use LinkedList instead of Array. List<Object>. or you can use List<Map<String,Object>>

Comment: An `ArrayList` is simple an implementation of `List` backed by an array.  It's best used when you need random access to the list.  Persisting objects to a file can be done in many different ways, you "could" use [serialisation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization), but it has limitations.  You could XML or JSON to represent the data and parse it at runtime.  This is probably a more common solution.  You could even have a "master" file which linked out to other files, maybe representing different categories, as an example